# Find cell farthest to the bottom of spreadsheet containing specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tables containing the employee names. I'm trying to locate the cell farthest to the bottom of my spreadsheet containing the value "Person".

```
Sub findperson()

Dim a As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(1)
    
        Set a = .Find("Person", LookIn:=xlValues)
        MsgBox a.Row
    
    End With

End Sub
```

My code locates the first value cell which contains "Person" e.g. returns 2 for `a.Row` when I would like it to return 12 (the bottom-most value).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `.searchdirection` of `.Find` to `xlPrevious`

```
Set a = .Find("Person", LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
```